# fire RaiseCanExecuteChanged when items of a Listview are changed

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, command

I'm using a MVVM pattern with Prism

I've got a list of Elements in an ObservableCollection, in my Model. In my View, i binded the ObservableCollection to a Listview, then i trye to display 1 button that is binded to a DelegateCommand called DoSomethingCommand. That means that each line of my Listview have a button to call DoSomethingCommand, with a CommandParameter binded to the ID of the element.

Constraint: DoSomethingCommand will change the status field of my element to "done". When an element is "done" i want the button to call DoSomethingCommand to be disabled.

So logically, all i have to do is have a canExecuteDoSomethingCommand delegate when i implement the command. But, the problem is when and how can i raise DoSomethingCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged? 
BTW Element is part of a third party dll that i can't modify it, but it already implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
<ListView BorderThickness="0" Width="Auto"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementList}"
              >
   <ListView.View>
     <GridView>
       <GridViewColumn Header="Actions">
         <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                     <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.DoSomethingCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ID}" >Accept</Button>
                </StackPanel>
             </DataTemplate>
           </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
```

Implemting the command

```
DoSomethingCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(executeDoSomethingCommand, canExecuteDoSomethingCommand);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Prism's EventAggregator, and I assume that you are since you're using Prism, then you can subscribe to an event and call RaiseCanExecuteChanged() on your DelegateCommand.

Something like this:

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<YourCompositePresentationEvent>().Subscribe((i) => { YourDelegateCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); });
```

Comment: that's interesting. Actually i'm not using EventAggregator so far as i only have one module now.
So what you're saying is when i update my elements in the Model, i should raise an event, and this event should be catch by the ViewModel to raise the RaisePropertyChanged? Using EventAggregator to link eveything? I'm going to try that

Comment: @kstarbucks51...That's right.  I think the EventAggregator is the best feature of Prism.  It facilitates communication between loosely-coupled parts.

Comment: using the EventAggregator was indeeda very good, and solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I have two solution to your problem:

First solution:

That would be great, if you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `Element` class. Maybe you can create another class and convert between them ? Your code will be look like this:

```
 public ICommand DoSomethingCommand { get; private set; }
    private void OnDoSomethingCommand(object param)
    {
        Element tmp = param as Element;

        if (tmp != null)
        {
            tmp.Status = "done";
        }                

        (DoSomethingCommand as DelegateCommand<object>).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    private bool CanDoSomethingCommand(object param)
    {
        Element tmp = param as Element;

        if (tmp != null)
        {
            if (tmp.Status != null && tmp.Status.Equals("done"))
                return false;
            else
                return true; 
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Second solution:

You can do this without invoke `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method.

```
 public ICommand DoSomethingCommand { get; private set; }
    private void OnDoSomethingCommand(object param)
    {
        Element tmp = param as Element;

        if (tmp != null)
        {
            tmp.Status = "done";
        }

        List<Element> refresh = new List<Element>(ElementList);
        ElementList.Clear();
        foreach (var item in refresh)
        {
            ElementList.Add(item);
        }          
    }

    private bool CanDoSomethingCommand(object param)
    {
        Element tmp = param as Element;

        if (tmp != null)
        {
            if (tmp.Status != null && tmp.Status.Equals("done"))
                return false;
            else
                return true; 
        }
        return true;
    }
```

[Here](http://sdrv.ms/PSfiFe) you have all sample code (ListViewDelegateCommand.zip).

Comment: Element already implements INotifyPropertyChanged, sorry it wasn't really clear (i wrote that question at 2:30 am).
First solution worked actually! It's not ideal because, the command ask to another service to change the status, then i received a confirmation from the service with the amended Element. So it's working, but i think it's because i'm lucky that the latency is very short. If i had to wait 1 minute to get the update, it probably wouldn't work.

Second solution is not doable, that would refresh the whole list, that could be very long. That would slow down the GUI a lot.